# is it possible to test Retina Display on simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, retina-display

How can you test Retina Display on a simulator if it is possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, run the application from Xcode, when the simulator opens go to Hardware->Device->iPhone 4

That will now have a 2x screen resolution.

Comment: is there a reason why i don't see the files with the '@2x-iphone` in the name going down the wire? i've got my emulator open as well as the Safari dev tools. I open the network tab on the dev tools, reload my page in the emulator, and am *not* seeing the '@2x-iphone' images going over the network.